# Error: Failed to load class on Spark+Mesos cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to submit the following job to my cluster, with Spark 3.0.0 and Mesos 1.9.

```
./bin/spark-submit \
        --name test2 \
        --master mesos://master:7077 \
        --deploy-mode cluster \
        --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
        --conf spark.master.rest.enabled=true \
        ./examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar 100
```

However, I have received the following error message.

> I0916 21:26:23.155861  8587 fetcher.cpp:562] Fetcher Info:
> {"cache_directory":"/tmp/mesos/fetch/root","items":[{"action":"BYPASS_CACHE","uri":{"cache":false,"extract":true,"value":"/spark-3.0.0-bin-SparkFHE/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar"}}],"sandbox_directory":"/var/lib/mesos/slaves/b61fd963-8537-48f0-9eb6-e26f3aa97265-S0/frameworks/92ca9c69-72c9-43d1-828e-ecc8bac62eff-0000/executors/driver-20200916212624-0041/runs/46a1e00e-0c01-47b5-82f5-a46ba5237321","stall_timeout":{"nanoseconds":60000000000},"user":"root"}
> I0916 21:26:23.165118  8587 fetcher.cpp:459] Fetching URI
> '/spark-3.0.0-bin-SparkFHE/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar'
> I0916 21:26:23.165141  8587 fetcher.cpp:290] Fetching
> '/spark-3.0.0-bin-SparkFHE/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar'
> directly into the sandbox directory W0916 21:26:23.168915  8587
> fetcher.cpp:332] Copying instead of extracting resource from URI with
> 'extract' flag, because it does not seem to be an archive:
> /spark-3.0.0-bin-SparkFHE/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar
> I0916 21:26:23.168941  8587 fetcher.cpp:618] Fetched
> '/spark-3.0.0-bin-SparkFHE/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar'
> to
> '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/b61fd963-8537-48f0-9eb6-e26f3aa97265-S0/frameworks/92ca9c69-72c9-43d1-828e-ecc8bac62eff-0000/executors/driver-20200916212624-0041/runs/46a1e00e-0c01-47b5-82f5-a46ba5237321/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar'
> I0916 21:26:23.168957  8587 fetcher.cpp:623] Successfully fetched all
> URIs into
> '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/b61fd963-8537-48f0-9eb6-e26f3aa97265-S0/frameworks/92ca9c69-72c9-43d1-828e-ecc8bac62eff-0000/executors/driver-20200916212624-0041/runs/46a1e00e-0c01-47b5-82f5-a46ba5237321'
> I0916 21:26:23.374958  8598 exec.cpp:164] Version: 1.9.0 I0916
> 21:26:23.387948  8614 exec.cpp:237] Executor registered on agent
> b61fd963-8537-48f0-9eb6-e26f3aa97265-S0 I0916 21:26:23.390528  8604
> executor.cpp:190] Received SUBSCRIBED event I0916 21:26:23.391326
> 8604 executor.cpp:194] Subscribed executor on worker4 I0916
> 21:26:23.391512  8604 executor.cpp:190] Received LAUNCH event I0916
> 21:26:23.392763  8604 executor.cpp:722] Starting task
> driver-20200916212624-0041 I0916 21:26:23.409191  8604
> executor.cpp:738] Forked command at 8622 20/09/16 21:26:25 WARN
> NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your
> platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable Using Spark's
> default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
> 20/09/16 21:26:25 WARN DependencyUtils: Local jar
> /var/lib/mesos/slaves/b61fd963-8537-48f0-9eb6-e26f3aa97265-S0/frameworks/92ca9c69-72c9-43d1-828e-ecc8bac62eff-0000/executors/driver-20200916212624-0041/runs/46a1e00e-0c01-47b5-82f5-a46ba5237321/**spark.driver.supervise=false**
> does not exist, skipping. Error: Failed to load class
> org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi. 20/09/16 21:26:25 INFO
> ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called 20/09/16 21:26:25 INFO
> ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory
> /tmp/spark-0c04f617-9daf-4a4b-8efe-e7d48e1eb06f I0916 21:26:25.802945
> 8601 executor.cpp:1039] Command exited with status 101 (pid: 8622)
> I0916 21:26:26.809671  8619 process.cpp:935] Stopped the socket accept
> loop

Within the above error message, I noticed that **spark.driver.supervise=false** is referenced in the executor path when trying to load the jar files.

> 20/09/16 21:26:25 WARN DependencyUtils: Local jar
> /var/lib/mesos/slaves/b61fd963-8537-48f0-9eb6-e26f3aa97265-S0/frameworks/92ca9c69-72c9-43d1-828e-ecc8bac62eff-0000/executors/driver-20200916212624-0041/runs/46a1e00e-0c01-47b5-82f5-a46ba5237321/**spark.driver.supervise=false**
> does not exist, skipping.

I think the problem of failing to load the class is due to this incorrect reference.

Any suggestion?

Looking into the debug message of spark-submit, I found the following.

```
Spark config:
(spark.jars,file:/spark-3.0.0-bin-SparkFHE/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar)
(spark.driver.supervise,false)
(spark.app.name,test2)
**(spark.submit.pyFiles,)**
(spark.master.rest.enabled,true)
(spark.submit.deployMode,cluster)
(spark.master,mesos://master:7077)
Classpath elements:
```

I noticed that **(spark.submit.pyFiles,)** is empty. I didn't plan to use python. Not sure why this option is turned on.

Furthermore, I tried debugging in the function "def doSubmit(args: Array[String])" within SparkSubmit.scala.

I tried to print the args array.

`for (arg <- args) { logWarning(s"doSubmit: $arg") }`

Somehow the following is included `--py-files` without any value.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in 3.0.0 and also present in 3.0.1.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32675

It's supposed to be fixed in 3.1.0 which has RC targeted for Jan 2021 https://spark.apache.org/versioning-policy.html

This issue is happening because --py-files gets appended even if you don't explicitly pass it to spark-submit. I applied the PR to 3.0.1 source and rebuilt the distributions and that fixed the issue for me.

Here's what I did:

1. Edit resource-managers/mesos/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/cluster/mesos/MesosClusterScheduler.scala

Replace line 538:

```
options ++= Seq("--py-files", formattedFiles)
```

With:

```
if (!formattedFiles.equals("")) {
  options ++= Seq("--py-files", formattedFiles)
}
```

2. Edit resource-managers/mesos/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/cluster/mesos/MesosClusterManagerSuite.scala

Replace line 595:

```
 "--driver-cores 1.0 --driver-memory 1000M --class Main --py-files  " +
```

With:

```
"--driver-cores 1.0 --driver-memory 1000M --class Main " +
```

3. Rebuild using: ./dev/make-distribution.sh --tgz -Pmesos

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information from the links provided in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.